# How can i show a set of png as a video?

Tags: java, png, video-streaming

The pngs are send from the server side one by one, how can i display it on the client side as a video?

Comment: First of all, i don't think this is the way video streaming work, so you might want to read up on that. Secondly, if you really want to do it that way, what is wrong with just updating the image as they are received one by one? You are going to have to give more information on this.

Comment: i am developing a software which similar to VNC,RDP. so i get a set of image data, and then send it to the client and show it out, is it a right way for me ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a video, you could put them into a Javascript slideshow to make it flow like some kind of video, or put them into an animated gif.